# Pyinstaller : Cannot include .mp3 files

Tags: python, pyinstaller, tic-tac-toe

I'm trying to create a stand-alone python application (Tic-Tac-Toe) using **pyinstaller**. I wrote the following commands in the command prompt:

> pyinstaller -w --onedir x_and_o.py
>
> pyinstaller --add-data "Sound;snds" x_and_o.py

The .mp3 files are saved in the folder "Sound". Everything was executed 'Successfully' but I'm still getting the following error:

```
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. 
https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
   File "x_and_o.py", line 216, in <lambda>
   File "x_and_o.py", line 30, in changeText
   File "x_and_o.py", line 182, in pop
 pygame.error: Failed loading libmpg123.dll: The specified 
 module could not be found.
```

Here's a snippet from my code:

```
pygame.mixer.init()

def pop_sound():
pygame.mixer.music.load(r"C:\Users\Dipesh\OneDrive\Desktop\Visual Studio Code\Tic-Tac-Toe Project\Sound\pop.mp3") # r means 'raw string'
pygame.mixer.music.play()

def Air_horn():
pygame.mixer.music.load(r"C:\Users\Dipesh\OneDrive\Desktop\Visual Studio Code\Tic-Tac-Toe Project\Sound\Air horn.mp3") # r means 'raw string'
pygame.mixer.music.play()

def game_over_sound():
pygame.mixer.music.load(r"C:\Users\Dipesh\OneDrive\Desktop\Visual Studio Code\Tic-Tac-Toe 
Project\Sound\gameOver.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

I've tried looking up for solutions online but couldn't find any solution to my problem.

I'm using Windows 10 and coding in VS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the following error:

```
pygame.error: Failed loading libmpg123.dll: The specified 
module could not be found.
```

I simply needed to [download this file](https://www.dllme.com/get/25787) and move it to my application folder.
You can read about **libmpg123** [here](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1KUBR_enIN869IN869&sxsrf=ALeKk00CbaYO8j0fYG3AqZ1qIjE0WOlLKg%3A1591192702243&ei=fqzXXs21DsOZ4-EPseOJ0As&q=what%20is%20libmpg123.dll&oq=what%20is%20libmpg123.dll&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoECCMQJzoECAAQHjoGCAAQCBAeOgYIABAHEB5QthhYqSBgzyNoAHAAeACAAe8BiAGUDJIBBTAuOS4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjN7KTe5uXpAhXDzDgGHbFxAroQ4dUDCAw&uact=5)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by editing `init_library` in the library file mpg123.py.  By hardwriting the location of the .dll into this method (if you need the dll you can acquire a compiled binary from the mpg123 site), and then using the pyinstaller flag to include the .dll, it will be correctly packaged into the exe.